# Node JS Asyncrounous Function Doesn't Return the Right Result

Tags: javascript, node.js

Have this `module.exports` file which returns a function to fetch some profiles using the gender parameter as the body of the request. 
Here, the function is asynchronous and waits for the `fetch` to return a result so it can proceed. I am using all the async js rules but still, it returns undefined.

I know that there isn't any problem in the URL or the API endpoint because I directly console logged it in `.then()` the promise returned by the `fetch`, it firstly consoles logs `undefined` and then it returns the original value.

Here's the code:

```
// Pre Configuration
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

module.exports = async (req, res, genderCode) => {
  const apiURL = req.apiURL
  const requestURL = `${apiURL}/featured?gender=${genderCode}`
  await fetch(requestURL)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        return data._embedded.compactProfiles
    })
}
```

Also where I call the function, I also use `await` there.
Can anybody tell what's wrong with it?

Comment: you didn't eturn anything from you exported async function. Maybe you meant `return await. . . `?

Comment: Don't use both `then` and `await` syntax.

Comment: you are mixing things up senior as the comments above are implying - have a read on [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) and on [using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't put a `return` statement in the anonymous function you export.

You await the value from the second `then` statement (although I'm at a loss as to why you are using `then` **and** `async`/`await`), and then do nothing with it.

```
module.exports = async (req, res, genderCode) => {
  const apiURL = req.apiURL
  const requestURL = `${apiURL}/featured?gender=${genderCode}`
  const res = await fetch(requestURL);
  const data = await res.json();
  return data._embedded.compactProfiles
}
```

Comment: Yeah I just realise, i can just return a promise instead os using async/await I'm such a dumbass